# If WEB_URL site fails to load in the webview, how to move to another URL - Android

Tags: android, android-webview

If WEB_URL site fails to load in the webview, how to move to another URL - Android

There's something I don't know when building an Android app.

The URL private final static String WEB_URL = "https://a.html"; ` is received as a URL and displayed in the webview.

```java
private final static String WEB_URL = "https://a.html";
```

If this URL doesn't exist

```java
private final static String WEB_URL1 = "https://b.html";
private final static String WEB_URL2 = "https://c.html";
private final static String WEB_URL3 = "https://d.html";
```

If the WEB_URL site fails to load in the `webview` due to a problem,
Load the web view with `WEB_URL1`
If it is not WEB_URL1, I want to automatically load the webview to WEB_URL2 and WEB_URL3.`enter code here`

I would like to know the code or example for this.
Thank you for teaching me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this by override `onReceivedError` method in `WebViewClient` like so:

```
 @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
           view.loadUrl(WEB_URL2);
    }
```